# Responsive independent 2 column layout

Tags: html, css, wordpress, grid, responsive

I'm currently developing a Wordpress blog theme - it must be fully responsive. I wanted to display a 2 column layout on bigger screens, having independent columns.
[I thought of something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORNr.png) 
the mobile page is no problem - but on the 2 column layout [I had problems like this (bottom image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JORNr.png)
I tried it with the **:nth-child()** selector + **floats**, but it didn't work.
The posts should be listed by date! 
would be really grateful if somebody could tell me a way solving this problem! thanks in advance.

**edit:**
NOT using bootstrap or any other grid system!

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: sorry forgot about that - not using bootstrap and any other framework!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have multiple elements that are just floated, but that wont work if the elements are of different heights. You will need to create two separate columns for those elements.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is rearrangement. How do I get separated columns back into a one column while maintaining the correct timeline. If I put 11 posts in 2 different divs (could do that easily with php), and make them 100% width on smaller screens, posts would be shown like: 1 - 3 - 5 - 7 - 9 - 11 - 2 - 4 - 6 - 8 - 10.

Comment: Gotcha. You're gonna need to use javascript. Here is a good plugin for it: http://masonry.desandro.com/